# php how to generate an id for each object in a foreach loop

Tags: php, facebook, loops, foreach

I have a php page that I am displaying everything in a database using a foreach loop. I have added a facebook comment box API in the loop so it is displaying on each iteration of the loop, My problem is when I comment on one thing, it displays on every object of the page.

I tried generating a unique id, the only problem is I need the ID to be the same on each page reload. Heres the code

```
<?php foreach($apps as $app){?>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h3><?php echo $app->app_name;?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $app->app_body;?></p>
    <br>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://localhost:8888/appshare/<?php echo uniqid(); ?>" data-numposts="3" width="100%"></div>
  </div>

 <?php }?>
```

Where it says echo uniqueid() id like to have something that just stores a number  for each object in the loop like 1,2,3... and keeps that same number on page reload. Any Ideas?

Comment: If your `$apps` come from a database, you can add an auto-increment id to the table those are coming from (if there isn't one there already). Then you can use `$app->id` just like you're getting the name and body.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I had actually tried that earlier but was just missing something in my model (using codeigniter).